# IE CSS Issues - Nothing is in the appropriate position

Tags: css, html, background, positioning, fixed

I hope this problem is something easily fixable as this website was meant to be a simple project turned into a mess! I'm not sure if this is a unique problem to the code that I've implemented or if it's something that happens often.

I've utilized divs and css to create a website where the background scales to the size of the window. Works exactly how I want it to in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE9, etc. BUT in IE < 9 it's being completely unreasonable! Someone please help as I'd really like to avoid coding this from the bottom up.

http://www.mwrenovationsllc.com

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: One thing I'd recommend is checking w3schools for the various CSS properties you used.  w3schools will tell you which is supportd by the various browsers, and thus you can tell what's not supported quickly (probably the issue).  You may need custom ie8 and earlier code, depending on what the issue is, or just a small change.  You can also come back at that point with a more specific question that is more appropriate for the site.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry about that - newb here!

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm pretty sure it's something with my fixed position background because the rest is basic css. Wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of IE are very picky about having a DOCTYPE set. Make sure your HTML structure has the following layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        // head contents here...
    </head>
    <body>
        // body contents here...
    </body>
</html>
```

If that does not work properly try using a more specific DOCTYPE instead such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

This worked, I'm almost embarrassed in it working.

Thank you so much!